# Whatsapp Desktop give error Phone Number shared via url is invalid

Tags: whatsapp

I have been using Whatsapp API URL https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=XXXXXXXXXXXX to send messages to customers, just today it started to give an error "Phone Number shared  via url is invalid"

This is only happening on the desktop app, using the same URL from phone opens up the mobile app and works as expected, is this something related to a rate limiting or some sort, I am using Whatsapp desktop app on Mac OS

Comment: You haven't given us any details besides an unhelpfully vague error message...

Comment: Same here, stop working.
I realized that if you have send a message previousle or yuo have the number in contacts it works.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue since Whatsapp Messenger app was updated on Mac OS. It still works fine when you use it on a web browser on your phone.

Comment: Its happening on web version also. It is probably a first step that whatsapp is taking to make its web version deprecated. does anyone know if there is a forum or channel in slack or discord to talk about this?

Comment: Same here, it's my CRM most active function, can't work at all...
Did Someone found a solution to this issue?

Comment: This is why I hate WhatsApp so much...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a new change introduced by Whatsapp. Earlier they allowed you to start a conversation with any number using their standard API url.

However, now it **only allows** you if the number is either:

- **Already present in your contact list**
- **You've had a conversation with that number in the past**

So in short, messaging to any number that is "**unknown to you**" is NOT allowed. Most likely this is done to reduce spam.

Ideally, they should display appropriate error message in this case instead of just saying "*Phone number shared via url is invalid.*"